# did emails store at queue

Tags: email, case

Set up - Email Administrator - Deliverability unable the checkbox
no mails will send to end user...   after updating field enable it
1.in this emails will store at queue  or not
2.if we enable then emails will trigger to end user or not???

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce will not queue emails. So if you switch the email sending off Salesforce won't queue emails. IE if you switch the email sending back on the users will not get a sudden flood of emails. If that's what you mean?

Comment: I'd reword this slightly for clarification. Salesforce.com does not queue emails when Deliverability is turned off. Otherwise, emails are queued and sent normally. They are queued in the sense that a failed transaction will also fail to send the emails, and those emails may not be delivered immediately anyways.

Comment: You seem to implying by saying "those emails may not be delivered immediately anyways" that a failed transaction will send an email? which isn't the case?

Comment: No. I'm simply saying that even successfully queued messages can take a while to send. The truth about emails is complicated at best. A failed transaction will never send an email, obviously, but a successful message can also be delayed indefinitely.